# How to change cell value within a column in reference to another cell value within another column in r?

Tags: r, weather, monthcalendar

I would like to replace the 'month' value by looking at the 'week' value. If it is week 52 then the month should be 12. How to do that across the data?

Example data:

```
   year month week
    2010 1 52
    2010 12 52
    2011 1 52
    2011 12 52
    2012 1 52
    2012 12 52
```

expected data:

```
year month week
2010 12 52
2010 12 52
2011 12 52
2011 12 52
2012 12 52
2012 12 52
```

Comment: There are weeks that contains days in two different months, no ? So you can't do what you want.

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington It depends on what the OP is interested in, though: they might want to get the month in which the week starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MrSmithGoesToWashington pointed out, if you look from the time perspective, it is not possible. But if you are just asking how to change any value based on the value in another column, you can do sth like that.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2010),
                 month = c(1, 12),
                 week = c(52, 52))

df %>% mutate(month = ifelse(week == 52, 12, df$month))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way.
If the year/week are between the year/week of the first and last days of December, the month is 12 else it's the recorded month.

```
yw <- with(df1, paste(year, week))
yy01 <- paste(df1$year, 12, 1, sep = "-")
yy31 <- paste(df1$year, 12, 31, sep = "-")
yy01 <- format(as.Date(yy01), "%Y %U")
yy31 <- format(as.Date(yy31), "%Y %U")
ifelse(yy01 <= yw & yw <= yy31, 12, df1$month)
#[1] 12 12 12 12 12 12
```

And assign this value the the column `month`.

```
df1$month <- ifelse(yy01 <= yw & yw <= yy31, 12, df1$month)
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
 year month week
    2010 1 52
    2010 12 52
    2011 1 52
    2011 12 52
    2012 1 52
    2012 12 52
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import data: df1 => data.frame
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L
), week = c(52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# Generate a sequence of dates, store as a data.frame: 
# date_range => data.frame
date_range <- data.frame(
  date = seq(
    from = as.Date(
      paste(
        min(df1$year),
        "01-01",
        sep = "-"
      )
    ),
    to = as.Date(
      paste(
        max(df1$year),
        "12-31",
        sep = "-"
      )
    ),
    by = "days"
  )
)

# Derive the month: month_no => integer vector
date_range$month_no <- as.integer(
  strftime(
    date_range$date,
    "%m"
  )
)

# Derive the week: week_no => integer vector
date_range$week_no <- as.integer(
  strftime(
    date_range$date,
    "%V"
  )
)

# Derive the year: year_no => integer vector
date_range$year_no <- as.integer(
  strftime(
    date_range$date,
    "%Y"
  )
)

# Create a lookup table: year_mon_week_lkp => data.frame
year_mon_week_lkp <- transform(
  aggregate(
    month_no ~ year_no+week_no,
    data = date_range,
    FUN = max
  ),
  month_no = ifelse(week_no >= 52, 12, month_no)
)

# Resolve the month using the week_no and the year: 
# month => integer vector
df1$month <- with(
  df1, 
  year_mon_week_lkp$month_no[
    match(
      paste0(
        year,
        week
      ),
      paste0(
          year_mon_week_lkp$year_no, 
          year_mon_week_lkp$week_no
      )
    )
  ]
)
```